# Asterisk Chan_motif.o, Chan_motif.so and Chan_motif.exports missing

Tags: asterisk, voip, google-talk, pbx

I was attempting to recompile asterisk with chan_motif when I noticed an XXX beside it. I then checked the directory /usr/src/asterisk-11.6.0/channels just to realise that Chan_motif.o, Chan_motif.so and Chan_motif.exports are all missing.  :? Only chan_motif.c is present. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That mean you not installed pre-request for this library.

For module you mention most likly it is libice or jabber code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things for chan_motif:

1. The res_xmpp module. This is dependent on the other dependency for chan_motif as well, which would be...
2. The iksemel library.

Note that when you move the cursor over an unselectable item in menuselect (one of those items with XXX), menuselect will tell you which modules and libraries the unselectable item depends on.